# Navigator thumbnail panel in QGIS

Tags: qgis, zoom, gui

Using QGIS, is there a way to add a navigation panel that shows a tiny coarse-resolution (zoomed out) version of the map, to illustrate which part of the continent that the main view-window is zoomed into? Like the inset or "locator" maps that you would find accompanying any scientific figure, providing an overview of the spatial context surrounding the more detailed map. (E.g. containing a point or rectangle that visually communicates the current extent of the primary map window.) So that you can tell "where you are" without needing to toggle the zoom level of the main window? (And ideally able to be used as a tool to pan more quickly/accurately across large expanses, like the "navigator" pane in most photo image editing software.)

Answer (score 2):

This needs two steps

- Add the 'overview' panel (View - Panels - Overview)
- Right-click on the layer that you want to have as overview and select: Show in Overview

You can remove the layer from the overview panel the same way

Once you zoom in you will see a red box showing the view extent of the map window.

Hope it works

Comment: is it possible to dock the overview window? I tried moving it like other panels (eg, navigator), but it doesn't exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Yes it is. A bit fiddly, but it does work.

Comment: I was finally able to get it to dock, but the behavior seems inconsistent. At least for me, it will only right after QGIS launches, before adding anything to the map.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the "Overview Panel"

From [the QGIS doc](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=overview#overview-panel) :

> 11.2.4. Overview Panel
>
> The Overview panel (Ctrl+8) displays a map with a full extent view of some of the layers. The Overview map is filled
> with layers using the Show in Overview option from the Layer menu or
> in the layer contextual menu. Within the view, a red rectangle shows
> the current map canvas extent, helping you quickly to determine which
> area of the whole map you are currently viewing. If you click-and-drag
> the red rectangle in the overview frame, the main map view extent will
> update accordingly.
>
> Note that labels are not rendered to the map overview even if the
> layers used in the map overview have been set up for labeling.